# Html table composed row by row, td in column to merge

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a html table that I composed row by row like this:

```
<tr  *ngFor="let _ of [].constructor(10);let fieldNumber = index">
  <td *ngFor="let version of versions; let versionNumber = index">
    ...
  </td>
</tr>
```

My problem is that now I want for some of the resulting columns to be composed of only one cell, that hs the height of all the rows in the table, something that could normally be achieved by using colspan: 0

Do you have any suggestions on how to achieve this?